# Android distro for reading?

Tags: ebook-reader

Is there an android distribution that presents a stripped-down ereader interface and nothing more?  The reason for this is just a matter of ultimate usability.

Comment: Android doesn't have "distros", and your custom ROM options are going to be heavily influenced by what device you have. This is possibly covered by [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

Comment: This is a classic case of asking about the supposed solution instead of asking about the problem to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Android is just a platform like OS that anyone can add toppings (apps) to.

If you want a really clean minimal OS good for E-reading then install Titanium Backup or [Root Uninstaller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rootuninstaller.free), and just uninstall all of it (including default Homescreen) and just leave your favorite E-reading app (Kindle, Aldiko, Cool Reader, whatever). This way you will have a dedicated E-book reader like device without resorting to flashing a new ROM.